# Form Processing ASP.NET

Tags: .net, forms

I have created a website survey that is in the footer of our site.  Obviously the footer is on every page within our site.

There is a link in the footer that opens a very basic include via jQuery toggle. (form.aspx)

Once the form is submitted it is sent to another page that is not using jQuery toggle for processing (processing-form.aspx). Which takes the user away from the page they might be visiting.

What can I do to keep the user experience in tact and not have to process on another page, and redirect back, or make a link "click here to return to the page you were on".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is to have your survey process the form submission via AJAX, which will allow it to be processed without a full round trip to the server. Once the form is submitted, you can then use your jQuery code to hide the form.

A nice article about accomplishing such a task can be found [here](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/).

Answer (score 1):

Use an HTTP handler instead of a separate page, and use jQuery to make an asynchronous call to the page and display some sort of "Thank you for responding" message in place of your survey.

http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/020417.htm